# My centroids from YOLO detection are drawn redundantly

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I am doing a project to detect crowd based on centroids of person, car and motorbikes. When drawing the centroid on a blank frame, it appears that the centroids are drawn redundantly. The code is as follows:

```
            
    for i, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
        x, y = centroid
        class_label = labels[class_ids[i]]
        centroid_color = color_dict.get(class_label)
        cv2.circle(cent_frame, (x, y), 3, centroid_color, -1)
        cv2.circle(cent_frame, (x, y), 15, centroid_color, 1)
```

Comment: Have a look at NonMaximumSupression. Opencv has a function for that.